# How to restore windows registers from saved desktop

Tags: desktop, registers

I save a few different windows registers using `M-x r w` and then save the entire desktop with `M-x desktop-save`.

I then restart Emacs and load the desktop using `M-x desktop-read`. If I do `M-x r j` do jump to one of the previously saved windows registers in the saved desktop I get an error message saying `Register doesn't contain a buffer position or configuration`.

If I do `M-x list-registers` every registry is described as `Register X contains a rectangle starting with an Unprintable entity`.

I do not run Emacs in a terminal, it's a full GUI Emacs and desktop-restore-frames is set to 't'. How should I do to save frame configurations between desktop sessions?

Comment: getting same issue... `(add-to-list 'desktop-globals-to-save 'register-alist)` didn't save registers after restarting emacs

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use window registers, use frame registers. Namely, save the configuration of the frames with `frameset-to-register`. It appears that Desktop correctly handles frame registers, but not window registers, and they perform largely the same function.